# RxJS share operator a problem inside *ngIf

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am beginning to get some proficiency in RxJS operators but I still have difficulty with some of them.    In implementing a search component I have the following code:

```js
      searchResult$: Observable<LunrDoc []>;
      searchResultLength$: Observable<number>;

      ngAfterViewInit(): void {

        // observable to produce an array of search hits

        this.searchResult$ = fromEvent<Event>(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
          debounceTime(1000),
          switchMap(e => this.ss.search((e.target as HTMLTextAreaElement).value)),
          share()
        );

        // observable to return the length of the array

        this.searchResultLength$ = this.searchResult$.pipe(
          map(sr => sr ? sr.length : 0),
          share()
        );
      }
```

And this is used in the template like this:

```html
    <p *ngIf="(searchResultLength$ | async) > 0">
      Total Documents: {{ (searchResultLength$ | async) | number }}
    </p>

    <p *ngFor="let doc of (searchResult$ | async)">
      <span *ngIf="doc.path" [routerLink]="doc.path" style="color: darkblue; font-weight: bold; text-underline: darkblue; cursor: pointer">
        {{ doc.title }}
      </span>
      {{ doc.content.substring(0, 400) }}
    </p>
```

What happens is when a non-null array is emitted by the `searchResult$` observable the rendered result in the first paragraph element as "Total Documents:" without a number after it.  The ***ngFor** decorated paragraph works exactly as expected.

The reason I believe is that the second `async` pipe gets activated and subscribes to the shared observable after the last value gets emitted.  So it never gets a "next" call.

Is there an RxJS operator to use instead of `share` to fix this situation?   Or did I miss something else?

Comment: Your explanation sounds reasonable and you can try to use `shareReplay(1)` instead.

Comment: I don't see a reason for `share` at all, do you really need it?

Comment: The share multicasts the observable such that the search API isn't hit for each subscription individually. The share on the length observable isn't necessary, though. The code could also use the "as" feature of ngIf to avoid a bit of repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ingo Bürk suggested. `shareReplay(1)` is probably what you are looking for. The 1 refers to the buffer size (how many values it should play back to you).

[Share replay docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html)

What I'll also suggest is to avoid creating multiple observables.

e.g. This creates two different subscribers.

```html
<p *ngIf="(searchResultLength$ | async) > 0">
  Total Documents: {{ (searchResultLength$ | async) | number }}
</p>
```

The alternative is:

```html
<p *ngIf="(searchResultLength$ | async) as searchResultLength > 0">
  Total Documents: {{ searchResultLength | number }}
</p>
```

#### Proposed Solution

Looking at the code and trying to understand the functionality, I think you can make these changes to get your desired output.

**Component:**

```js
searchResult$: Observable<LunrDoc []>;
    
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.searchResult$ = fromEvent<Event>(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
    .pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        switchMap(e => this.ss.search((e.target as HTMLTextAreaElement).value)),
    );
}
```

You wouldn't need `share` or `shareReplay` as they don't seem to offer any functionality that your template will need. Unless there is some more code in the template that isn't visible in your question.

The `this.searchResultLength$` observable also seems redundant as that is just the `length` property on the value returned by `this.searchResult$`.

**The template:**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="{searchResult: searchResult$ | async} as vm">
    <p *ngIf="vm.searchResult.length > 0">
        Total Documents: {{ vm.searchResult }}
    </p>

    <p *ngFor="let doc of vm.searchResult">
        <span *ngIf="doc.path" [routerLink]="doc.path" style="color: darkblue; font-weight: bold; text-underline: darkblue; cursor: pointer">
            {{ doc.title }}
        </span>
        {{ doc.content.substring(0, 400) }}
    </p>
</ng-container>
```

The wrapper `ng-container` will always display because the `ngIf` condition will evaluate to a truthy value.

**Note**

Consider looking into the `ditinctUntilChanged` operator, when dealing with inputs that trigger an observable: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html

Comment: This is really interesting.  The https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay documentation is just a stub but going just by the name doesn't this replay all values for the later subscribers?   Also I was completely unaware of the "as" syntax I'd like to try that.

Comment: Ive updated the link to one with some explanations: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html. Yes it replays the values for late subscribers (or in other words observers that subscribe after a value was already emitted)

Comment: What about the use of publishBehavior?   Is that an alternative and if so what are the pros and cons?   Maybe you can update your answer rather than answer in a comment.

Comment: updated with a modified solution. Feel free to update your question with the full code in the template

Comment: I am really really liking this answer and i think this is the basis of a good code pattern I will use.  If I could checkmark this post 4 times I would.   Let's leave my original post as is so that anyone who encounters it can see the difference.